# Where can I download historical market capitalization and daily turnover data for stocks?

Tags: dataset

There are plenty of sources which provide the historical stock data but they only provide the OHLC fields along with volume and adjusted close. Also a couple of sources I found provide market cap data sets but they're restricted to US stocks. Yahoo Finance provides this data online but there's no option to download it ( or none I am aware of ).

- Where can I download this data for stocks belonging to various top stock exchanges across countries by using their ticker name ?
- Is there some way to download it via Yahoo Finance or Google Finance ?

I need data for the last decade or so and hence need some script or API which would do this.

Answer (score 7):

Quant SE is better place for questions related to getting financial data:

- [What data sources are available online](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)
- [Market capitalization data | Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/search?q=market+capitalization+data)

Answer (score 3):

As far as gathering data goes, you can check out **Quandl** (there's a tutorial on using it with **R** on [DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/how-to-work-with-quandl-in-r) if you're interested).

In addition, Aswath Damodaran's [site](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/adamodar/New_Home_Page/data.html) contains a lot of helpful datasets. Though they aren't updated that frequently, they may still be useful, especially as a benchmark for comparing your own output (from the scripts you will inevitably need to write to calculate the necessary metrics).

And, again, **Quant SE** is probably a better place to be looking...

Answer (score 1):

Something changed on this web site recently. The code directly below works for me.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
tckr = ['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN','FB','GOOG']

i = 1

url_list = [(s, url_base + s) for s in tckr]

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

with open('C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AAA.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for t, url in url_list:
        print(i)
        i = i + 1
        print(t, url)
        print('Scrapping ticker {}...'.format(t))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
        writer.writerow([t])
        for row in soup.select('.snapshot-table2 tr'):
            writer.writerow([td.text for td in row.select('td')])
```

I deleted the older, non-working, code.

Comment: This would require something like sellenium in 2021, you get a DDOS protection message